# Custom Parameter along with app_remove

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-analytics

I want to send a `User Property` along with the `app_remove`. How can I do that ?I have a added a `User Property` as a parameter in the console. But it doesn't give any result.

It has been more than 48 hours that I have added the parameters. Also, I am using Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Did you find a way to know who uninstalled the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add code to set an Analytics User Property with the [setUserProperty()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setUserProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

Please refer this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties#set_user_properties

Comment: yes, I have set the User Property but I want the User property to show up along with app_remove, so that I may know who removed the app.

Comment: You can use the filter in FA console to distinguish users who remove the app: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-firebase-playground.appspot.com/o/console.png?alt=media&token=b077f2f5-c460-432a-bdf1-7021a2b693b5.